# Spring Boot 4 and Thymeleaf web and mail together not working

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am facing some problem in using Spring Boot 4 along with Thymeleaf web together with its mail.

If I use Spring Boot 4 with Thymeleaf web alone it is able to work without any issues. The problem starts when I include the Thymeleaf mail configurations

```
   @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Bean(name ="templateEngine")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private TemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

If I try to build and run with this, the page fails to load. So I have updated the code with including the web template.

@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

```
@Bean(name ="templateEngine")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(webTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

private TemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return templateResolver;
}

private TemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(2);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

This is the error that is returned when the page is loaded:

```
    2016-10-14 14:56:57.137 ERROR 3875 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

What configuration is required so that both the thymeleaf web and mail templates can be used correctly with spring boot ?

This is my spring properties for thymeleaf

`spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.view-names=index
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true`

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` should work without any configuration (`spring boot` does magic for you)

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for configurae it just creating the bean `TemplateResolver` in a configuration class with something like, should work.

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);

    return emailTemplateResolver;
}
```

Then you must add your mail templates in `src/main/resources/templates`.

So, for example if you create a template called `mymail.html` you should process with the SpringTemplateEngine bean. Inject it where you need it:

```
@Autowired
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

And then process the mail adding the name of the file template wihtout `.html` extension and add as text to your `JavaMailSender` like the next example:

```
 String body = templateEngine.process("mymail", ctx);
 javamail.setText(body, true);
```